# Start animation when condition is true

Tags: python, tkinter

I want a button to move across the screen but only after the user has typed in at least one character into the input box but my button is moving across the screen at start up.  What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
import time

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
xVelocity = 1
yVelocity = 1
window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window,width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()


#Create input box
E1 = Entry(window)

#Display input box
canvas.create_window( 200, 150, window = E1)


btn = Button(canvas, text='Click me!', width = 10, height = 2, command = window.destroy)
button_image = canvas.create_window(0,0, window = btn, anchor = NW)

while E1 != "":
coordinates = canvas.coords(button_image)
if(coordinates[0]>=(WIDTH-75) or coordinates[0]<0):
    xVelocity = -xVelocity
if(coordinates[1]>=(HEIGHT-35) or coordinates[1]<0):
    yVelocity = -yVelocity
canvas.move(button_image,xVelocity,yVelocity)
window.update()
time.sleep(0.01)
```

window.mainloop()

Comment: You cannot use ```while E1 != ""``` directly. You need to use something like ```e1 = E1.get()``` and then use ```e1``` in the ```while``` loop. Also, you can use ```E1.bind("<Key>", move)```. Create a function called ```move(event)``` and add the loop inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don't use while loop in a tkinter application as it will block the tkinter `mainloop()`.  Use `.after()` to replace the while loop.

Second `if E1 != ''` should be `if E1.get() != ''`.

```py
...

def check_loop():
    global xVelocity, yVelocity
    if E1.get() != "":
        coordinates = canvas.coords(button_image)
        if coordinates[0] >= (WIDTH-75) or coordinates[0] < 0:
            xVelocity = -xVelocity
        if coordinates[1] >= (HEIGHT-35) or coordinates[1] < 0:
            yVelocity = -yVelocity
        canvas.move(button_image, xVelocity, yVelocity)
    window.after(10, check_loop)

check_loop()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Canvas, Entry, NW
import time

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
xVelocity = 1
yVelocity = 1
window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window,width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()


#Create input box
E1 = Entry(window)
e1 = E1.get()

#Display input box
canvas.create_window( 200, 150, window = E1)

def move(event):
    global yVelocity, xVelocity, coordinates, WIDTH, HEIGHT, button_image
    while True:
        coordinates = canvas.coords(button_image)
        if(coordinates[0]>=(WIDTH-75) or coordinates[0]<0):
            xVelocity = -xVelocity
        if(coordinates[1]>=(HEIGHT-35) or coordinates[1]<0):
            yVelocity = -yVelocity
        canvas.move(button_image,xVelocity,yVelocity)
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)

btn = Button(canvas, text='Click me!', width = 10, height = 2, command = window.destroy)
button_image = canvas.create_window(0,0, window = btn, anchor = NW)

E1.bind("<Key>", move)

window.mainloop()
```